# Can I use the CYK-Algorithm for a Grammar where all results still have a Variable in them?

Tags: context-free

Let the Grammar be G = ({S}, Σ, P, S), where Σ = {⟨,⟩,[,]} and

```
P: S → ⟨S⟩, [S], SS, ε 
[⟨ → ⟨[
```

Can I still use the CYK-Algorithm and if yes then how would I do it for a word like ⟨[]⟩ ?

Comment: I don't understand your notation in the quoted block.  I don't understand what either line is trying to say.  Can you use more standard notation for grammars?  ote that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What are the guarantees on what kinds of grammars [CYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) is guaranteed to work for?  If you read some resources on CYK, you should be able to answer that.  Then, is this grammar one of those kinds of grammars?  You have used the [tag:context-free] tag.  Is this a context-free grammar?  What are your thoughts on that?  Please [edit] your question to show your progress and your thoughts.  (continued)

Comment: We're not particularly looking for questions that are the statement of an exercise-like task and a request for us to solve it for you, as those are unlikely to be helpful to you in the long run or helpful to others after you.

Comment: Your grammar doesn't appear to be context-free. CYK only works for context-free grammars.

Comment: Please don't append "Edit: more stuff".  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755. If you discover the answer to your own question, please don't edit the question to put it in the question.  Instead, write an answer using the 'Your Answer' box below.

Answer (score 1):

the Grammar is not context-free and thus the CYK -Algorithm wont work